# Как скрыть свойство инфоблока Bitrix во Frontend?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте, есть инфоблок со своими свойствами, но некоторые из них не должны быть показаны во Frontend но должны быть в админке.
Как сделать? Стандартными способами похоже не получится? Спасисбо заранее.

Comment: А как выводятся эти свойства? В настройках компонентов можно выбрать какие свойства отображать в публичной части. Если же это самопис без возможность настройки тогда только в коде править.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста где это делается, я с битриксом в первый раз столкнулся

Comment: Нужно знать как эти свойства выведены, каомпонент какой хотябы знать.

Comment: Bitrix virtual appliance version 7.0.1
1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 17.0.5, стандартный интернет магазин биртикса

Comment: Ух, сейчас в поисках ответа как раз на этот вопрос, но в нашей админке, к примеру, на сегодняшний день в этом разделе настроек отсутствует подборка отображаемых свойств. Есть ли ещё пути, как подлезть?
Щедро выводит все-все свойства. Хочу ограничить для технических, нужных мне параметров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполните следующие действия для того, чтобы указать, какие именно свойства должны выводиться на странице детального просмотра товара:

1. Заходите на страницу с товаром в публичной части сайта
2. В серой админ-панели сверху переходите в "режим правки". [image: режим правки]
3. Наводите курсор на блок с карточкой товара, переходите в настройки компонента Каталог. [image: перейти в настройки компонента]
4. Находите в списке настроек раздел "Настройки детального просмотра", а там настройку "Свойства" - выбираете те свойства, которые нужно выводить. [image: выберите свойства]
5. Жмете "Сохранить".

Comment: большое спасибо за помощ!